# Qml/C++ Memory Leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qml

i have the next problem, I use Qt 5.5, and create a application with C++ and Qml, but in a Gui where one model are updated every the second the memory grows and grows the memory , how i can stop the grow or manage the memory.

The application works fine, but the problem is in the Gui(page) where a set of models are updated and in the gui are refreshd every second (make a Post and with the answer update the model), in that case after some minutes the memory begins to grow(without limit apparently), i change the model to C++(original are in qml, changed to QQmlListProperty class, like i post the code here), but i don't get change in memory usage, i try to use dynamic objects in every method of the process of update with same result, and finally i try to disconnect some notifications of the objects (only the necessaries), but too fails in control of memory.

Here the header of C++ QQmlListProperty (QmlListBombs)

```
class QmlListBombs:public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> bombs READ bombs CONSTANT) 
   Q_CLASSINFO("DefaultProperty", "bombs")

  public:
   QmlListBombs(QObject *parent=0);
   QQmlListProperty<BombModel> bombs();
   static void append_bomb(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> *list, BombModel *bmb); 
   static BombModel *bombAt(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> *property, const int index);
  private:
      QList<BombModel*> m_bombs;
  signals:
     void bombsChanged();
```

The number of bombs when the app is running, always is the same (for that the property is constant)

Here the method bombsAt and constructor more

```
  //QmlListBombs.cpp
  //constructor
  QmlListBombs::QmlListBombs(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
  {}

  QQmlListProperty<BombModel> QmlListBombs::bombs() {
    return QQmlListProperty<BombModel>this,&m_bombs,&QmlListBombs::bombsSize, &QmlListBombs::bombAt);
       }

   //append function, i not use this funcion to append to list in C++
   void QmlListBombs::append_bomb(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> *list,  BombModel *bmb){
      QmlListBombs *bmbsList=qobject_cast<QmlListBombs *>(list->object);

       if(bmbsList){
         bmb->setParent(bmbsList);
         bmbsList->m_bombs.append(bmb);
       }
      }

      void QmlListBombs::insertBomb(){
           BombModel *newBomb=new BombModel(island);
           newBomb->setParent(this);
           m_bombs.append(newBomb);
       }

       BombModel* QmlListBombs::bombAt(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> *list, const int index){
           return static_cast< QList<BombModel *> *>(list->data)->at(index);
        }

       int QmlListBombs::bombsSize(QQmlListProperty<BombModel> *list){
          return static_cast< QList<BombModel *> *>(list->data)->size();
       }

       //update bomb method, the qjsonobject is from the answer from remote server request
       void QmlListBombs::updateBombs(const QJsonObject &reqStatusPumps){
         int index=0;

          QJsonObject arrayDataStatusReq=reqStatusPumps.value("pumpsList").toObject();
          while(index<sizeQmlListBombs()){
                if(m_bombs.at(index)->getStatusBomb()!=arrayDataStatusReq.value( m_bombs.at(index)->getPumpNumber() ).toInt())
                 m_bombs.at(index)->updateStatusPump( arrayDataStatusReq.value( m_bombs.at(index)->getPumpNumber() ).toInt() );

            index++
      }
    }

   int QmlListBombs::sizeQmlListBombs() const{
       return m_bombs.size();
   }
```

The header of BombModel and part of methods:

```
class BombModel: public QObject{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString numberBomb READ getPumpNumber CONSTANT) 
  Q_PROPERTY(int status READ getStatusBomb NOTIFY statusChange)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString statusName READ getStatusName NOTIFY statusNameChange);
 public:
  void updateStatusPump(const quint16 &_statusPump){
             if(this->status!=_statusPump){
                 this->status=_statusPump;
                 changeStatusName();//this function are only a switch where the status are evaluated
                 emit statusChange();
                 emit statusNameChange();
             }
  }
  int getStatusBomb() const{
      return this->status;
  }
  QString getStatusName() const{
     return this->statusName;
  }
  void BombModel::changeStatusName(){
     switch(status){
       case 0:
         statusName="Out";
         break;
       case 1:
         statusName="Free";
         break;
       case 2:
         statusName="Ocuped";
         break;
       ...
       ...
       default:
         statusName="Error";
         break;
     }  

  private:
   QString numberBomb;
   int status;          
   QString statusName;

  signals:
    void statusChange();
    void statusNameChange();
```

From the previous model only have some signals because some data (like numberBomb, never changes, only change status and statusName).

And in the main object i declare the list of QQmlListProperty like a context property.

```
view->rootContext();->setContextProperty(QString("listBombs"), listBombs);
```

The function who get the actual status is:

```
QByteArray responseStatus=catchStatus( jsonStatusBombs );
```

Like i say before i don't have problem with visualization, update my problem is the usage of memory.

Here my Qml file:

```
 GridView{                
          width: parent.width; height: parent.height;
          anchors.top: parent.top;
          cellWidth: 174; cellHeight: 117;

          id: arrayBombs;
          model: listBombs.bombs;

          delegate: BombModel{
               numberBomb: model.numberBomb;
               statusBomb: model.status;
               statusText: model.statusName;
         }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a memory leak? QML is a memory hog, and is negligent with the release of resources. In my experience, I create a gigabyte worth of objects, I delete them, run garbage collection and only 200-300 MB are released. Next time I allocate the objects, memory usage is higher, but not quite 1.3 GB - most of the memory will be reused, but not all.

Comment: i don't sure, was my first theory, but now with what you says maybe i will wait to the limit (for now i only see ~900 MB after 1 1/2 day and in that moment i exit from the app).

Comment: Check how much of this memory is allocated on the JavaScript heap. You can either do this via the profiler in the Qtcreator or by setting QV4_MM_STATS environment variable to 1.

Comment: thanks, i probe this to check the problem, i make a trick solution, put a screensaver after X minutes in idle and with that i can gets contains the memory size, but i'm not satisfied with that solution